# Subspace and open set on $E^1$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A=\{0 \} \cup \{\frac {1}{n}|n=1,2,3, . . . \}$ be a subspace of $E^1$

**My question :**

(a) is the singleton set $\{\frac {1}{n}\}$ open in $A$ ?

For all $n \in N$, the singleton $\{\frac {1}{n}\}$  is a closed subset of $E^1$. Let $X=\cup \{\frac {1}{n}\} $. Then, since the sequence $\{\frac {1}{n}\} \subset X$  but $0 \notin X$, X is not closed.This  shows that it is not always true that the union of an infinite collection of closed sets is closed.

(b) is $\{\frac {1}{n}|n=1,2,3, . . . \}$ open in $A$

(c) If $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in the subspace $A$, is it possible $U$ being a finite set ?

I don't understand to solve question b and c, anyone can help me or some hint. Thank you

Comment: Sets are not doors.

Comment: For reference, this means that one ought not confuse "closed" with "not open", as you may be inclined intuitively to do by analogy with doors, as was done in (a).

Comment: For any topological space $E$ and $S\subset A\subset E,$ if $S$ is closed in $E$ then $S$ is closed in $A.$ ... So $\{0\}$ is  closed in $A$ because it is closed in $E^1$... So $\{1/n: n\in N\}=A$ \ $\{0\}$ is open in $A.$... Furthermore   $  S(n)=A \backslash \{1/n\}$ is closed in $E^1$ for any $n\in N$ so $\{1/n\}=A$ \ $S(n)$ is open in $A$.

Comment: @user254665 is this solution for question a and b ?

Comment: Yes.  For c, if $U$ is a nbhd of $0$ in the space $A$  then $0\in V\cap A\subset U$ for some open $V$ in the space $E^1.$ Since $V\supset (-r,r)\supset (0,r)$ for some $r>0$ we have  $U\supset \{1/n: n\in \mathbb N\land 1/n<r\}=$ $=\{1/n: n\in \mathbb N\land n>1/r\}$ which is an infinite set.

Answer (score 0):

I can always find small enough open interval $I_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{\frac{1}{n}\}=A\cap I_n$. So $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is open in $A$.

The set in (b) is a union of open sets in $A$ so is open in it. Any neighborhood of $0$ would contain infinitely many points of $A$ as it would have to be an intersection of some open interval containing $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $A$ and any such interval has infinitely many points of $A$.

Comment: You might want to construct $I_n$ explicitly. It is rather easy.

Comment: You can also use $(0,1)$ to solve (b)...

Comment: You might also want to cite the Archemedean Principle for (c).

Comment: @DHMO how to prove it using $(0,1)$ ? do you think my solution for question a is correct ?